# Horizontal Scrollbar in C programming

Tags: c, user-interface, horizontal-scrolling

Can you please let me know how to use a horizontal scrollbar in C screens (UI)? We are using an SQC file, which contains C and SQL stmt, and RC file for screen modification.

I enabled horizontal scrollbars in the XXX.rc (xxx-program name) file via VS and compiled the code, but the horizontal scrollbar isn't working on the C screen, and I'm unable to see scrolling for horizontal. Can you please help me understand the logic behind this? I've referred to some of the stack overflow links for this topic, but no luck yet. My requirement is that once data gets loaded into C screens and the data is big and reaches beyond my screen, I should be able to use the horizontal scrollbar to view the hidden data on the same screen instead of expanding the screen size.